# Why is SoftApConfigurations.Builder hidden for me?

Tags: android, android-wifi

I'm trying to create a hotspot with a pre-defined SSID, and I want to do that with a StartLocalOnlyHotspot() method that includes a SoftApConfigurations argument. The only problem is that the SoftApConfigurations.Builder is hidden. I'm running android 30, does anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.